# Rspec before block scope inconsistant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm having scope issues when using RSpec's `before(:all)' block.

Previously I was using `before(:each)`, which worked fine:

```
module ExampleModule

    describe ExampleClass

        before(:each) do

            @loader = Loader.new

        end

        ...


       context 'When something' do


            before(:each) do
                puts @loader.inspect # Loader exists
                # Do something using @loader
            end

            ...

        end

    end

end
```

But switching the nested `before(:each) block to`before(:all) means loader is nil:

```
module ExampleModule

    describe ExampleClass

        before(:each) do

            @loader = Loader.new

        end

        ...


        context 'When something' do


            before(:all) do
                puts @loader.inspect # Loader is nil
                # Do something using @loader
            end

            ...

         end

    end

end
```

**So why is @loader nil in the before(:all) block, but not in the before(:each) block?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the `:all` blocks happen before any of the `:each` blocks:

```
describe "Foo" do
  before :all do
    puts "global before :all"
  end

  before :each do
    puts "global before :each"
  end

  context "with Bar" do
    before :all do
      puts "context before :all"
    end

    before :each do
      puts "context before :each"
    end

    it "happens" do
      1.should be_true
    end

    it "or not" do
      1.should_not be_false
    end
  end
end
```

Output:

```
rspec -f d -c before.rb

Foo
global before :all
  with Bar
context before :all
global before :each
context before :each
    happens
global before :each
context before :each
    or not
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Rspec documentation on hooks](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-14/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks), `before :all` hooks are run prior to `before :each`.

Comment: But aren't they run in order of scope? Surely anything in the describe group is run before anything in the context group? Or have I got that wrong?

Comment: You have got that very wrong, and probably ought not to be using `before :all` at all.

Comment: @Pedr: You have got that wrong. There would be logical problems if any `before :all` block could access something setup in an `each` block - for example *which* `each` block's output would it interact with, given tests may be run in any order?